# Practice exam question. Set theory

Tags: elementary-set-theory

I'm doing these practice exam questions and am stuck.

Given

$A1 = ( n ∈ Z | 2|n )$

$A2 = ( n ∈ Z | 3|n )$

$A3 = ( n ∈ Z | 6|n )$

Remember $a|b$ means a divides b.

Consider

$B_1 =  (· · · , −4, −2, 0, 2, 4, . . .)$

$B_2 =  (n ∈ Z |n/6 ∈ Z )$

$B_3 =  (3k | k ∈ Z )$

$B_4 =  (4 + 2k | k ∈ Z )$

$B_5 =  (A1 ∩ A2 )$

$B_6 =  (A2 ∪ A3 )$

$B_7 =  (A2 − A1 )$

$B_8 =  (n ∈ Z | n ≡ 0 (mod 3) )$

$B_9 =  (n ∈ Z | n ≡ 3 (mod 6) )$

The exercise is:

a) **Name for each of the sets B1-B9 which set A1-A3 it is equal to or none if it isn't equal to any one set.**

My own answer is:

$A_1=B_1=B_4.$

$A_2=B_3=B_6=B_8.$

$A_3=B_5=B_9.$

b) **What is the cardinality of the set A1?**

I believe it is countably infinite since it can be put into a one-to-one correspondence with natural numbers.

Comment: Why would $B_1=B_6$?  $3\in B_6$ for example.

Comment: Use `$\{ X\}$` for $\{ X\}$.

Comment: It wouldn't be equal to $B_6$.

Comment: Ok...Why would $B_3=B_7$?  $6\in B_3$.  I'm just picking individual equalities to test.  You ought to do the same.

Comment: How can $B_8$ equal $A_2,A_3$ at the same time?

Comment: A number of the equalities are incorrect.  I suggest you go back and check each one carefully.

Comment: I'll check them. I thought that since 3 divides a2 and a3 then it would be equal to them.

Comment: $A_1=B_1=B_4.$

For A2

$A_2=B_3=B_6=B_8.$

For A3

$A_3=B_5=B_9.$

Answer (score 1):

- $A_1=B_1=B_4=\{\dots,-4,-2,0,2,4,\dots\}$
- $A_2=B_3=B_6=B_8=\{\dots,-6,-3,0,3,6,\dots\}$
- $A_3=B_2=B_5=\{\dots,-12,-6,0,6,12,\dots\}$
- $B_7=B_9=\{\dots,-9,-3,3,9,\dots\}$

check yourself and if things are unclear then let me know.

Comment: I missed the fact that $B_9 $ would have a remainder of 3.

I got A1 and A2 right and almost got A3 right. I hadn't though of B2 because I didn't understand if n/6 meant that 6 divides n.

Comment: Is it countably infinite?

Comment: No, $n/6$ doesn't mean $6$ divides $n$, but $n/6\in\Bbb Z$ does

Comment: All these set are indeed countably infinite.

Comment: $n/6\in\mathbb Z$ is exactly the same statement as $n=6m$ for some $m\in\mathbb Z$ or equivalently $6\mid n$.